# Flutter CRUD Database Operations on Parse - Back4app

Tags: database, flutter, back4app

I want to use back4app as my database but i don't know if it has a persistent cache like CloudFirestore during Read operations? I plan on working with the Parse SDK (Rest Api) or are there some extra setup I need to do?

Comment: Please take a look at this link: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/tree/master/packages/dart#getting-started It is possible to initialize the SDK to use the CoreStoreSembastImp as the coreStore and it will persist data on the device.

Comment: @Davi Thank you